# Unable to change the config on Anaconda .condarc file

Tags: python, anaconda

There's a following configuration:

```
channels:
  - admin

show_channel_urls: true
allow_other_channels: true

proxy_servers:
  http: http://user:pass@172.16.30.20:8080
  https: https://user:pass@172.16.30.20:8080

ssl_verify: true
```

my proxy:172.16.30.20 port:8080

I'm trying to run:

```
C:\Users\Dipjul>conda create -n tfp3.6 python=3.6
```

And getting the following error:

```
Solving environment: failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/admin/noarch/repodata.json>                      
Elapsed: 00:03.075530                                                                                                    
CF-RAY: 49b32ad89ebb897b-MAA                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the                                                         
requested channel with url: https://conda.anaconda.org/admin
```

Comment: Why is the channel called `admin`? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Is your goal to install from a local repo, or anaconda.org?